# insert selected option into table

Tags: php

I have this code and I'm trying to put the selected state in a subcat table.
So far it returns an empty value. I'm not sure if this is clear or not, but all I want is: select a state from the select option and submit it. I want to get the selected state name into my table subcat.

```
enter <?php
include("connect.php");
$state = $row['states']; //Select name
if (isset($_POST[submit])){
$query = "INSERT INTO subcat (sub_name) VALUES ('$state')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" name="form">
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM   state");
echo "<select name='states'>
<option value=''>Select a state</option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[name]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" />
</form> here
```

Thanks

Comment: You have to use $_POST['states'] to get the value of selected option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$state = $row['states']` to `$state = $_POST['states']`

```
<?php

include("connect.php");    
if (isset($_POST[submit]))
{
   $state = $_POST['states']; //Select name
   $query = "INSERT INTO subcat (sub_name) VALUES ('$state')";
   mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}

?>
<form action="" method="post" name="form">
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM   state");
echo "<select name='states'>
<option value=''>Select a state</option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[name]</option>"; // if you want to 
//get the name into table, then use like this 
//echo "<option value='$row[name]'>$row[name]</option>";  or  
//echo "<option>$row[name]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now it inserted the id of the state from state table instead of the name.

Comment: This is because you put the option values as id, if you want the name, then change it to `$row[name]` or remove the value attribute from slecect options

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
enter <?php
include("connect.php");
if (isset($_POST[submit])){
$state = $_POST['states'];
$query = "INSERT INTO subcat (sub_name) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($state)."')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" name="form">
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM   state");
echo '<select name="states" id="states">
<option value="">Select a state</option>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" />
</form> here
```

Dont forget to use mysql_real_escape_string to prevent SQL injections. I have replaced $state = $row['states']; with $state = $_POST['states'];

I dont know where u got $row from...

The above will insert the states name into the database.

Comment: Thanks man, now I am getting the id instead of name of the state.

Comment: If you use selects in your form fields it always parses the value back. So always put in the value="" the value you need to insert it into your database. Dont forget to use mysql_real_escape_string to prevent SQL injections.

And use $_POST to get the value from a form which has the method="POST".